# Simulate a sql reproducible example

Tags: sql, impala

I want to know a way to write a minimal reproducible example in impala.

Here is my way.

```
select 1 as x1, 2 as x2 union all
select 3 as x1, 4 as x2 union all
select 5 as x1, 6 as x2 union all
select NULL as x1, 8 as x2
```

Is there any way to simulate an example more easily?

Comment: This seems pretty easy, so I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, @Gordon Linoff  I just want to know is there any way to simulate it by less code.